# Adding text/time stamp to individual frames of the video

Tags: image, opencv, video, time

I made the video using the ".tiff" image files through openCV. Now, I want to add timestamp or text to each frame. Each frame in my data represents 14 seconds. I am running the video at 1 frame per second and there are 51 frames.

What is the procedure to add the time or text on each frame individually?

I used the following code:

```
img_array = []
for filename in glob.glob('D:\\KMC2_data\\rahim_data_frames\\test\\*.tiff'):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    height, width, layers = img.shape
    size = (width,height)
    img_array.append(img)
out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 1, size)
for i in range(len(img_array)):
    out.write(img_array[i])
out.release()
```

Comment: Determine the current timestamp and use `cv2.putText()`

Comment: You can also check out this detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59183585/editing-frames-while-recording-a-video-with-opencv/59215047#59215047) :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to nathancy comment the current "Time:" in the cv2.puttext at a position can be added, let's say at 10th row and 10th column in the image using:

```
import datetime
img_array = []
for filename in glob.glob('D:\\KMC2_data\\rahim_data_frames\\test\\*.tiff'):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    cv2.putText(img,"Time: "+str(datetime.datetime.now()),(10,10),2,0.8,(255,255,2)) 
    height, width, layers = img.shape
    size = (width,height)
    img_array.append(img)
out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 1, size)
for i in range(len(img_array)):
    out.write(img_array[i])
out.release()
```